# Android: Making the width and the height of a custom view equal

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am using a custom view (CoordinateGridView) in XML like this:

```
<com.android.catvehicle.CoordinateGridView
    android:id="@+id/coordinateGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I am trying to get the width of the CoordinateGridView to fill the entire width of the screen. The height should then match the width -- therefore, the custom view should always be drawn as a square.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `onMeasure` function in `CoordinateGridView`:

```
public void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
  super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
  int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
  setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

See https://github.com/chiuki/android-square-view for a full example.